# How to Output Lists without Commas or Brackets?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

When trying the below code, is there a more elegant way to output the numbers without the commas or brackets? `Grid`, as suggested in other threads, is not behaving as expected, nor did trying to force a blank space with `Row[list," "`] between each item work.  The intent is to copy and paste the cleaned output for other uses.

```
encode:=FormPage[{"message"->"String", "key"->"Integer"},
 Row[Times[ToCharacterCode[#message],#key]
  ,Spacer[4]]&]
CloudDeploy@encode
```

Comment: Suggest you look at `TableForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to turn everything into a string

```
list = Range[5];
StringJoin[ToString /@ Riffle[list, " "]]

1 2 3 4 5
```

You can copy-paste this output directly.

Answer (score 2):

I use when I do not want nothing between elements of list `Grid[list, Frame->None]`

Comment: Hmmm.. This is the output in the cloud once updated: `Grid[{38628, 34632, 34965, 38295, 10656, 34965, 38295, 10656, 38628, 34632, 33633, 10656, 33633, 36630, 33300}, Frame -> None]`

Comment: One update to Axon Pués' answer. I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. Grid requires at least 2 dimensions. So youll have to do Grid[{list}, Frame->None]

Comment: `Row[`list`]` is a quick way to do this.

Comment: `Grid` requires a 2D array, that's why it's not working. You'd need `Grid[List @ {38628, 34632, 34965, 38295, 10656, 34965, 38295, 10656, 38628, 34632, 33633, 10656, 33633, 36630, 33300}, Frame -> None]` for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Range[5];

StringRiffle[list, " "]
```

[image]